# Call a service at startup with a launch file

Tags: navigation, roslaunch, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to call a service from a launch file once at startup?
We want to call the service /global_localization of AMCL the first time we launch our robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11271/call-a-service-at-startup-with-a-launch-file/) by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 408 on 2011-09-21

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just have the call be its own node in the launch file:

```
<node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="global_loc" args="call --wait /global_localization" />
```

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 24

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-09-21**:
That was my first idea, too. But as Lorenz wrote above, roslaunch tends to pass additional parameters which let rosservice choke.

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2012-10-22**:
This worked for me, I just added that line verbatim directly under my AMCL launch line. I like this method better, it just feels right, light, and clean. :)

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-02-28**:
Apparently this no longer works in Groovy....  Comment here if you want this feature fixed I suppose: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/180

**Comment by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) on 2015-05-05**:
This works under hydro i just tested with this line of code in launch file under ubuntu 12.04:

**Comment by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) on 2015-12-18**:
This still works under indigo like charm!

**Comment by [renweiros](https://answers.ros.org/users/29408/renweiros/) on 2017-04-28**:
This also works under kinetic! Thank bhaskara for the answer:)

**Comment by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on 2019-09-10**:
still works in melodic

**Comment by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on 2020-12-10**:
Thanks works for me in melodic , for Gazebo service,

```
<node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="rosservice" args="call /gazebo/reset_simulation"/>
```

**Comment by [Den](https://answers.ros.org/users/82056/den/) on 2021-11-16**:
This worked for me in noetic with the following:

The service arguments were:

```
Header header
string name
string type
```

and the following was added to the launch file:
`<node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="rosservice" args="call /start '[0, 0, 'map']' '' ''" />`

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-12-13**:
For a slightly more complicated example (involving nested quotes):   `<node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="open_door" args="call --wait /gazebo/apply_joint_effort '{joint_name: &apos;door_panel_frame_joint&apos;, effort: 100.0, start_time: {secs: 0.0, nsecs: 0.0}, duration: {secs: 1.0, nsecs: 0}}'"/>`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know how if it is possible in a clean way. A quick and dirty hack for Linux would be the misuse of the launch-prefix attribute.

In your package foo, create a file named kickstart with the content

```
#!/bin/bash
rosservice call --wait /global_localization &
exec "$@"
```

Then, make it executable using

```
chmod +x kickstart
```

Finally, add the following attribute to one of your  declarations in the launch file:

```
launch-prefix="$(find foo)/kickstart"
```

This will coax roslaunch into executing the kickstart script with the real node launch command line as parameters. The script performs the service call and executes the remainder of the command line, thus launching the node.

The --wait parameter ensures that the service is actually available, and the ampersand at the end of the rosservice line runs the call in the background, so the node launch will not be delayed.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on 2011-09-21**:
Thanks, it worked

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-09-21**:
Sorry. My bad. Never mind... I didn't read your code carefully enough. :)

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-09-21**:
That is why the kickstart script is needed. The rosservice call is completely independent of the node launch in the exec line below.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-09-21**:
I think that won't work because roslaunch passes additional parameters such as renamed topics and the node's name which causes rosservice to die with an exception. I think the only way to call the service is to not use any cmd line params in the script but put the complete command there.